# display:none stopping initial translate3d animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CwmMQ/3/

I am trying to create a very basic off-canvas menu using jQuery and GPU accelerated animations.

```
.profile-oc-menu { display: none; }
```

Using display:none was the only way I was able to get the right side off-canvas menu to work correctly so that the page is not scrollable horizontally.

The problem is that the initial animation does not slide in. Subsequent animations slide in correctly though.

I have tried a number of different ways to fix this including adding a '.closed' class with the following declarations:

```
.closed { visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden, width: 0; }
```

Interestingly enough, this method does work, but it leaves white space where the 'hidden' element was sitting. Even stranger is that when you resize the browser window (even by 1px) the white space will disappear and the menu works perfectly.

Can anyone help me to understand why the initial animation (click the right button) fails to animate?

<strike>**Solved by JoshC!**
http://jsfiddle.net/CwmMQ/4/</strike>

<strike>**Updated demo incorporating JoshC's solution that also fixes height issue on panels (for those interested)** - 
http://jsfiddle.net/CwmMQ/5/</strike>

**UPDATE**
Adding overflow: hidden to the body element disabled page scrolling. I tried to find a work around to this, like adding overflow-x: hidden, but that didn't really work, so I had another shot at it.

Please see the following example that fixes the initial problem. Please feel free to use it in your projects. :)
http://jsfiddle.net/CwmMQ/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I can think of would be to add `overflow:hidden` to the `body` element and remove `display:none` from the slider.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/CwmMQ/4/)

```
body {
     overflow:hidden;
}
```